# Is a cheap English translation available of Tsiolkovsky's "Outside the Earth"?

Tags: history, colonization, reference-request, soviet-union, rocket-equation

Anyone know where to pick up a copy of Konstantin Tsiolkovsky's science fiction book titled "Outside the Earth" (alternately titled: "Beyond the Planet Earth" and "Beyond Earth") ?

The reviews that I've read said the book is bad science fiction. Still, I am curious to know what one of the pioneering thinkers of aeronautics thought. I've been looking for a cheap English translation. Here's some links to the book.

**Too Expensive**: [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1414701640), [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0000CKO3P)

**Not in English**: [Abebooks](https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=30621410506&cm_sp=Searchmod-_-NullResults-_-BDP)

The editions from Abebooks appear to be in English but they are not. I ordered one. Only the cover is in English.

Comment: I know where to find original Russian text for free, but would machine translation satisfy? For example here https://tsiolkovsky.org/ru/nauchnoe-nasledie/. Some of the works even have English translation there, but "Outside the Earth" has not, unfortunately.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Which is the book? I tried finding "земной шар" in the list but it doesn't show up.

Comment: Found it. It's listed as "Вне Земли" here.

Comment: @SpaceDisgrace Would you like it to make an answer? Self answer are always appreciated and it also help future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [1960 translation by Syers](https://archive.org/details/beyondplaneteart00tsio), which you link to, is available for short loan (1hr) from the Internet Archive / Open Library.

The ISFDB has a reasonably complete list of editions, which identifies [a 1963 translation by Dutt](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?310519) in a volume called *Call of the Cosmos*. This volume is [available to read via the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.216303/page/n7/mode/2up). (I am a little unclear on the copyright status here, but it's not restricted-access, anyway...)